# Sqlite:The constructor is undefined

Tags: android, sqlite, sqliteopenhelper

I have created **DBAdapter** class which is responsible for making a connection to a Database and does any query and finally close the connection.

I have another class which it is not inherited from **Activity** class(**ReminderBeep**), but i have to use my DBAdapter in this class.

**Actually i don't know how can i manipulate the DBAdapter constructor to make the connection.***

The error is:  **The constructor DBAdapter(ReminderBeep) is undefined**

DBAdapter  is:

```
public class DBAdapter {

    static final String DATABASE_NAME = "MyDB";
    static final int DATABASE_VERSION = 2;
    final Context context;   
    DatabaseHelper DBHelper;
    SQLiteDatabase db;

    public DBAdapter(Context ctx)
    {
        this.context = ctx;
        DBHelper = new DatabaseHelper(context);
    }
    private static  class DatabaseHelper extends SQLiteOpenHelper
    {
        DatabaseHelper(Context context)
        {
            super(context, DATABASE_NAME, null, DATABASE_VERSION);
        }

        @Override
        public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db)
        {              
        }

        @Override
        public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion)
        {
        }
     }

    //---opens the database---
    public DBAdapter open() throws SQLException 
    {
        db = DBHelper.getWritableDatabase();
        return this;
    }

    //---closes the database---
    public void close() 
    {
        DBHelper.close();
    }
    public void insert(String sql)
    {
      db.execSQL(sql);      
    }
}
```

BeepReminder is:

```
public class ReminderBeep   
{
    public void DeleteDailyActivities()
    {
        DBAdapter db=new DBAdapter(this);
        db.open();
        String sql="delete from DailyWorks";
        db.insert(sql);
        db.close(); 
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

ReminderBeep is not extendig Activity. But DBAdapter want a Context as paramter,

```
    DBAdapter db=new DBAdapter(this);
```

`this` refers to `ReminderBeep`

Comment: Yes i know,but as there is no XML file for BeepReminde i can not use _extends Activity_

Comment: than you should rethink your design

Comment: Do u have any idea for constructor?

Comment: you still need a Context in order to use the DB. That depends what you need to achieve

Comment: you have an application,so lets asume that somewhere you have a class that extends Activity. Pass this activity to the BeepReminder and call the DBAdapter with it.

Comment: @mihail -Thanks, nice idea. Imagine in _Setting_ i inherted _activity_
U mean this? **DBAdapter db=new DBAdapter(Setting.class);**

Comment: well, something like this. I was thinking about create a member in ReminderBeep of type Activity and set it through the activity you call it from, then use this member for the DBAdapter.

Comment: Setting.this, if Settings extends Activity